# js checking for idle time not working

Tags: javascript

Im using the below code to check for idle time using javascript but the alert msg is not triggered when I click or keypress.

http://jsfiddle.net/wnm7cvhd/

code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('hi')
    var idleTime = 0;
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 30000); // 1 minute

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        alert('mouse moved')
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        alert('key pressed')
        idleTime = 0;
    });

});

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 1) { // 20 minutes
        alert('No action')
    }
}
```

Comment: your fiddle is working.

Comment: there is no click handler... keypress is working

Comment: strange..its not working on my machine

Comment: One problem I can see the scope of `idleTime`.. it is a closure variable in the dom ready handler so will not be accessible in `timerIncrement`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/adbrspqt/1/

Comment: Your comments make no sense. "30000" is not 1 minute, and `idleTime > 1) { // 20 minutes` is not 20 minutes. It's 1 interval of 30,000 milliseconds, or 30 seconds.

Comment: @meagar most probably reduced the gap for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be working for me. However, be aware that there is NO click handler, so you will not be able to intercept a click event. I have updated [Your Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/wnm7cvhd/1/) in the following manner...

- Moved the `idleTime` out of the `ready` function scope and made it global so that `timerIncrement` increment can also access it. Otherwise, you will get errors
- Replaced all calls to `alert` with `console.log`...`alert` is a bit intrusive
- Changed the `setInterval` timeout to 5 seconds for illustration purposes and avoid having to wait one minute to see the "No Action" message

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler are working fine... based on your comment about the fiddle I posted above... I guess that the problem is the scope of the variable `idleTime`.

The variable `idleTime` is declared within the dom ready handler method, so it will be available inside the scope of the dom ready handler onlye... but the method `timerIncrement` is declared outside the scope of the dom ready handler... So it [should give an error](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/adbrspqt/4/) in your console saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: idleTime is not defined`.

The solution here is to more the method `timerIncrement` inside the dom ready handler so that it can access the closure variables defined in the dom ready handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('hi')
    var idleTime = 0;
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 minute

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).on('mousemove keypress click', function (e) {
        console.log('reset: ', e.type)
        idleTime = 0;
    });


    function timerIncrement() {
        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        if (idleTime > 1) { // 20 minutes
            console.log('No action')
        }
        $('#result').html(idleTime)
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/adbrspqt/)

Comment: actually, `setInterval` is running on every second, to set it to one minute it should be 60000 (1000 * 60)

Comment: @Leo yes... but as a developer I don't like to wait for 60 sec to see whether it is working... those values can be changed later once the code segment is working fine

Comment: Got it, just thought I dropped a comment coz it might be misleading for someone else